# Excel Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have two columns of values in excel I want to format. 
If two Rows in Column A match, check column B to see if those two row's values match also. If they don't match, highlight the rows.

For example, the first columns first two rows values match so I want to check the second column to see if they match. They do not so both rows should be highlighted. The third and fourth match, and the second column for those rows also match, so these should not be highlighted.

```
 Number  Tool
 227974  9285
 227974  9219
 229703  9219
 229703  9219
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in the top left, select the data cells and create a conditional format with condition:

```
=OR(AND($A2=$A3,$B2<>$B3),AND($A1=$A2,$B1<>$B2))
```

And set it to highlight as you would like.